# Слово "огорошить"

Tags: фразеология

Откуда пошло выражение "огорошить кого-то"? При чем тут горох?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Горох точно ни при чем.
По одной из версий - от "огородить", по другой связано с грохотом.